# Python's .text : Couldn't get it to work

Tags: python

I've been trying to get the .text thingy in Python which converts html codes into readable text to work but still no luck.

Let's say I have the following code :

```
import urllib

url = ['http://google.com','http://bing.com']

for i in url:
    html = urllib.urlopen(i).read()
    print html.encode('utf-8').text
```

The code works once I remove the .text in the last line but I've seen people using that in tutorials without any problem at all. Any idea why couldn't I get it to work ? lol

Thank you very much !

Comment: Strings have no 'text' attribute....never had, never will

Comment: BeautifulSoup elements have a text property... That's what this looks like to me.

Comment: Where is BeautifulSoup used here?

Comment: It's not, I'm saying that may be the confusion.

Comment: Op could shed some light on its own code by providing the source of information used for writing this code.

Comment: Now there's a helpful suggestion. @E-Law : What tutorial(s) have you been looking at?

Comment: Thank a lot for all the help and answers guys ! I really appreciate every single one of them ! I guess that I made a fool out of myself as I was following a BeautifulSoup tutorial on Youtube which introduced me the .text function but did not know that it can be only used on something which is scraped with BeautifulSoup but at least now I know hahaha. Seems that I still have a very very long way to go !

Answer (score 3):

```
import urllib

url = ['http://google.com','http://bing.com']

for i in url:
    html = urllib.urlopen(i).read()
    print html
```

No need for `encode` or `text`, just can print the `html` write after `read()`. I would suggest that you use [`python-requests`](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/).